# How to store to Firebase with complex table in Angular 7

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database in FIrebase that has this stucture:

```
Collection     Document       Collection               Document
Shooters    => SOME DRINK =>  Name: "SOME DRINK"
                              Price: 50.50
                              Ingredients          =>  "Ingredient One"    =>  Price: 3.11
                                                                               Volume: 2
                                                       "Ingredient Two"    =>  Price: 5.50
                                                                               Volume: 3
                                                       "Ingredient Three"  =>  Price: 1.50
                                                                               Volume: 1
```

and I have a model like so:

```
export class Drink {
    Name: string;
    OrderType: string;
    Price: number;
    Ingredient: Ingredient[];
}

export class Ingredient {
    Name: string;
    Detail: IngredientDetail
}

export class IngredientDetail {
    Price: number;
    Volume: number;
}
```

This is the data I get in my console:
[image]

I need to save this values in my firestore db. I came up with this code...

```
public AddDrink = (model: Drink) => {
    const data = Object.assign({}, model);
    console.log(data);
    this.fireStore.collection(model.Name).add(model.Name)
  }
```

Can you please show me how to store this kind of model into my firestore? Most of the tutorial I see is they just save one data to a table. Thank you so much.

Please refer to the image below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to add a document into a subcollection try this for example:

```
public AddDrink = (model: Drink) => {
    const data = Object.assign({}, model);
    console.log(data);
    this.fireStore.collection('Shooters').doc('B52').collection('Ingredients').add(...)
  }
```

In this [repo](https://github.com/JoeBeer/tandemPartner/blob/master/functions/searchesEndpoint.js) you can see an example for that kind of problem. Just take a look at the `searchesCollection` `const`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you Sir.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)